# For Loop for both column contents and colname

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a for loop that will run through each column of the dataframe, reorganise it so I can plot it, and then use ggplot to plot. I just have no idea how to assign the column name that corresponds to the column `i`.

Calling `i` only gets me the column values without the name.

`d` is the dataframe I'm working with.

```
for (i in (d[c(6:45)])) { #how do I get colname!!??
ddplysummary <- ddply(d, c("CS.NCS", "Sex", "Group"), summarize,
                      N    = sum(!is.na(COLNAME),
                      mean = mean(COLNAME, na.rm = TRUE),
                      sd   = sd(COLNAME, na.rm = TRUE),
                      se   = sd / sqrt(N))

ddplysummaryomit <- na.omit(ddplysummary)

ddplysummaryomitunitedcol <- unite(ddplysummaryomit, Treatment_Status, c(CS.NCS, Group), remove=TRUE)

x <- c("NCS_Con", "NCS_PNS", "CS_Con", "CS_PNS")

ddplysummaryomitunitedcol %>%
  mutate(Treatment_Status =  factor(Treatment_Status, levels = x)) %>%
  arrange(Treatment_Status)  

title <- paste(COLNAME)
p<- ggplot(ddplysummaryomitunitedcol, aes(x=Sex, y=mean, fill=Treatment_Status)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(~Sex, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() + theme( strip.background  = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
                      panel.border = element_blank(),
                      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major.x=element_blank() ) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  labs(title=COLNAME,
       y = "grain") +
  scale_fill_manual(values =c("#f77f00","#d62828", "#EAE2B7","#fcbf49"),
                    name="Status\nTreatment",
                    labels=c("- PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "- PNS\n+ Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n+ Chronic Stress")) 

figurenamep <- paste("figure_", COLNAME, ".jpeg")
jpeg(file = figurenamep)
p
dev.off()
}
```

I was thinking of using `c(colnames(d[c(6:45)]))` but I don't know how or where.

Comment: Did you try colnames(d)[i]?

Comment: yes - it returns an error `Error in [.data.frame(d, i) : undefined columns selected`

Comment: When initiatiating your for loop - use `for (i in colnames(d)[6:45])` - the `[` needs to come after the colnames() call. I've never used ddply, but I suspect there's a simpler way of acheiving your desired result. Suggest you add some sample data.

Comment: Thank you @JayAchar unfortunately that still only loops over the column names, rather than the column contents as well. I've found that I have to use this ddply function to get my data into the format that ggplot can use.

Comment: colnames(d) will output a string vector of column names. I see that you use this string as the title of your plot. If you want to use the data in this column too, you would need to reference `d[[COLNAME]]`